# sql filtering results of alias column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we filter for an Alias name?  For example, in query below, for alias OLB, if we want to say WHERE OLB > 0

```
SELECT
loan.lnr
,loan.lamount - SUM (memrepay.mprinc) AS OLB
,lstatus

FROM
 loan
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memrepay
  ON loan.lnr = memrepay.lnr

WHERE
loan.tstart >= N'2013-07-07T14:00:00' 

GROUP BY loan.lnr, lamount, lstatus

Order By lnr
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions?

Comment: SUM is used in the code

Comment: Oops. Sorry, did obviously not read carefully enough...

Comment: @jarlh used Group BY to get total of mprinc values in all rows.

Comment: @Indian - sorry didn't notice this question was asked before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Derived table

```
select t.* from
(
SELECT
loan.lnr
,loan.lamount - SUM (memrepay.mprinc) AS OLB
,lstatus

FROM
 loan
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memrepay
  ON loan.lnr = memrepay.lnr

WHERE
loan.tstart >= N'2013-07-07T14:00:00' 

GROUP BY loan.lnr, lamount, lstatus
) as t where OLB>0
Order By lnr
```

or use HAVING clause and use the expression

```
SELECT
loan.lnr
,loan.lamount - SUM (memrepay.mprinc) AS OLB
,lstatus

FROM
 loan
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memrepay
  ON loan.lnr = memrepay.lnr
WHERE
loan.tstart >= N'2013-07-07T14:00:00' 

GROUP BY loan.lnr, lamount, lstatus
HAVING loan.lamount - SUM (memrepay.mprinc) >0
Order By lnr
```